# Leer 2 valores desde teclado en Haskell online

Tags: haskell

Estoy usando un compilador de Haskell online y me gustaría poder leer dos valores desde teclado (desde el cuadro input) dos números pero tira error y no sé como corregirlo.

```
g::Float -> Float -> Float
g n u   = 2 - (7/(5**n*u))

main :: IO ()
main = do 
        n <- getLine
        u <- getLine
        putStrLn (show (g (read n u :: (Float->Float->Float))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `read` tiene la siguiente firma:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

Estás intentando llamarla con dos argumentos de tipo `String` (`n` y `u`) en lugar de con uno sólo; tienes que aplicar la función `read` por separado a cada dato.

Por otra parte la anotación de tipo que proporcionas (`:: (Float->Float->Float)`) es la de la función `g`, pero una vez pasados los argumentos a esta, el tipo es simplemente `Float`. No es necesario que especifiques el tipo para los resultados de `read`, ya que Haskell puede inferirlo por el tipo de la función `g`.

```
g :: Float -> Float -> Float
g n u = 2 - (7/(5**n*u))

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    n <- getLine
    u <- getLine
    putStrLn (show (g (read n) (read u)))
```

Comment: ¿Y como hago para leer tuplas desde el cuadro de texto?

Comment: Se llama los valores de entrada bajo un mismo paréntesis.
Por ejemplo si las variables n y u fueran las variables de una tupla, sería así:
putStrLn (show (g (read n,read u)))

Answer (score 0):

Pude sacar el ejercicio definiendo también el tipo de dato en los valores de la entrada

```
g::Float -> Float -> Float
g n u = 2 - (7/(5**n*u))

main :: IO ()
main = do 
        n <- getLine
        u <- getLine
        putStrLn (show (g (read n :: Float)(read u :: Float)))
```